# How can make empty in each column while adding new rows in a table

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I  have a table with the column customer name, Address, Salary etc. But when I add the new  row in the table using button btnUpdate , the previous row column  value  would be  placed in the corresponding column of the  new row . How can I make it empty  column in the new row while adding it . Here is the code

```
public class EditHolidayEntVM
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public int DepotNo { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public decimal NetHrs { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public string FromDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

    public decimal HolidayEnt { get; set; }

}
```

Html

```html
<table id="tblEntry" class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Date From</th>
                                    <th>Date To</th>
                                    <th>Net Hrs</th>
                                    <th>Holiday Entitlement</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>edit
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromDate, new { htmlAttributes = new {  @class = "form-control datepicker w-100" } })</td>
                                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ToDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker w-100" } })</td>
                                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NetHrs, new { @id="netHrs", htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100" } })</td>
                                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HolidayEnt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control  w-100", @readonly="readonly" } })</td>
                                    <td><a href="" title="Delete Rows">Delete</a></td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row padding-top-ten center-block">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <button type="button" id="btnUpdate" name="submitButton" value="DeleteAtt"
                                        class="btn btn-primary form-control" onclick="AddNew();">
                                    <i class="fa fa-save"></i><span class="padding-left-ten">Add New Row</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<script>
 function AddNew() {
       var newRow = $("#tblEntry tbody tr").first().clone();
        var row = $("tbody").append(newRow);
       netHrs.val("");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: First, can you edit your code so that it works in the Snippet you've included (by including jQuery, and by replacing the `<td>` contents with representative data, rather than trying to use asp.net in the demo). I read the question as: "how can I insert a new row of empty cells into the `<tbody>` element?" Is that correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: So if I am not misunderstood your question, you want your previous row values become empty when enter new value into it right? Or you want to append both values(Old+new)?

Comment: If add new row initially  and I have typed values in each column . Then I append another row , the previous row column  value should not be copied in to new row column. How can I  Append new row with empty value when I add second row

Comment: Share your full model and backend code so that it can be reproduciable quickly.

Comment: I have given full model and html code .

Comment: Please have a look on the solution and let me know if that works expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are cloning the full table with existing value. So to achieve your goal you have to copy new row with empty value. So the easiest way is to get last child element and make it value empty.

***Implementation:***

Just replace your `AddNew` function like below

```
<script>
    function AddNew() {
        var newRow = $("#tblEntry tbody tr").first().clone();
        var row = $("tbody").append(newRow);
        $("tbody tr:last-of-type td input").each(function (index, el) {
            $(el).val("");
        })
    }
</script>
```

***Output:***

[image]

Hope it would resolve your problem.